# in vb.net how do I declare a public variable from a private sub

Tags: vb.net, variables, private, public

I am creating Labels dynamically from a private sub, and I want to be able to do something when the user clicks on them. However, I can't use "Dim withEvents blah..." because it says withEvents can't be used on a local variable but I also can't use "Public withEvents blah" from within my Private Sub. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: attach a click event handler when you create the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create dynamic control, you can add a handler for it

```
Dim mylbl As New Label
mylbl.Name = "button1"
mylbl.Text = "hi"
Me.Controls.Add(mylbl)

AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf AllLabels_Click
```

This is your Handler Sub

```
Sub AllLabels_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim lbl As Label = CType(sender, Label)

    MsgBox(lbl.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: That does not work for private variables. If you want to add an eventhandler to a control, the control must be created using "withEvents" which can only be done on Public variables.

Comment: By "variables" I mean dynamically created controls.

Comment: @user2018388, Public vs private is how they are accessed not how they are wired to events!

Comment: @user2018388, all dynamically added control must have handlers added the way matzone showed.

Comment: @user2018388, it sounds like you're having a problem with your handler's definition. Note that in this example there is no `Handles` keyword after `Sub AllLabels_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)`.

Comment: "WithEvents" only works with one control anyways (whatever was last assigned to the WithEvents variable).  AddHandler is definitely the way to go.  This is not a "private" variable, it is a "local" variable.  This local variable does NOT go out of scope when the sub  exits because not only does the form have a reference to it in its Controls() collection, but there is also a reference to it via the wired handler.

Comment: OK, I now see how it works. The "handles" thing was throwing me off. Thanks Matzone.

Comment: How do I mark this as answered? I clicked on the green check mark, but it still says "unanswered"

Comment: @user2018388 .. it's OK just make a green check ! thanx !